# Not understanding this structure typedefs

Tags: c, gmp

looking at the source code of GMPlib (the Gnu library for multy-precision calculations) I found this kind of code for building its mp*_t structures. And I have replicated it in various other works I have done, but I don't fully understand it.

```
typedef struct
{
  int _mp_alloc;           /* Number of *limbs* allocated and pointed
                              to by the _mp_d field.  */
  int _mp_size;            /* abs(_mp_size) is the number of limbs the
                              last field points to.  If _mp_size is
                              negative this is a negative number.  */
  mp_limb_t *_mp_d;        /* Pointer to the limbs.  */
} __mpz_struct;
```

I understand that this defines the 'shape' of a structure with two integers and a `mp_limb_t` and typedefs it to `__mpz_struct`

Then comes this line:

```
typedef __mpz_struct mpz_t[1];
```

And after a while, this other one:

```
typedef __mpz_struct *mpz_ptr;
```

I understand that the second one is typedefining `__mpz_struct *` to `mpz_ptr` (Which is used in the function prototypes)

But I don't understand what the first one does and why it works so I can declare a mpz_t. Can anyone explain why it works?

Thanks!

Comment: What an awesome idea, typedef `_struct` as a postfix into the type name, so you don't have to write `struct ` as a prefix. Argh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to understand a `typedef` is the rule *Define it like you use it*. In other words, when you declare a `typedef` you're making a new name, but should you remove the `typedef` keyword you'll get **an object of the aliased type**.

For example:

```
typedef __mpz_struct mpz_t[1];
```

This makes a new type name, called "mpz_t". But if we rewrite:

```
__mpz_struct some_obj[1];
```

we immediately understand it makes an array of whatever `__mpz_struct` is. So now we know what the new type `mpz_t a` does: it makes an array of `__mpz_struct` with one element.

Comment: Ok, I think that now, with your answer and the one from @AProgrammer I understand what it is doing. Thanks! I failed to see that mpz_t would create an array with one element.

Answer (score 1):

The first one typedefs mpz_t to an array of one __mpz_struct (the syntax of typedef is the same as that used for declaring an object, except you're declaring a type).

As an aside, typedef pointers isn't a terribly good idea as it makes it difficult to be properly const correct

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef __mpz_struct mpz_t[1];
```

defines mpz_t as an array of one __mpz_struct. The interest is that if you do

```
mpz_t x;
```

you defines x as an array of one __mpz_struct. If you do

```
void f(mpz_t p) { ... }
```

you define f as a function taking **a pointer to a __mpz_struct**, so you can call

```
f(x);
```

and it will call f, passing it a pointer to the first (and unique) element of x and f may modify x. You have thus a way to simulate pass by reference. As second interest is that your are loosing the possibility of doing

```
mpz_t x, y;

x = y;
```

Why is it interesting? Because __mpz_struct contains a pointer. And copying the pointer is not the right thing to do, you want the copy what is pointed as well.

BTW `va_list` is sometimes defined in the same way and that explains the constraint on its use.

Answer (score 0):

An array in C is actually equivalent to a pointer since the array is a pointer pointing to the first element of the array.
Here, `mpz_t` is simply defined to point to a array of 1 `__mpz_struct`

Hope it helped.